# ORA-01722: invalid number for a simple query

Tags: oracle, numbers, varchar, ora-01722

I noticed the same topics here but I just couldn't find the answer because of my noob skill in databases, I tried a couple of answers but didn't work, apologies.

I have 5 tables and triggers for each of them if the user INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE

After I inserted the data into `TRAFFIC, (date (varchar30), input_quant (varchar30), output_quant (varchar30), status (varchar30) )`

I've tried a simple query

```
select sum (input_quant)status from traffic;
```

But the error pops out:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Is it because of the type (`VARCHAR`)?

In the table TRAFFIC and SUPPLY I had to DISABLE the FKs so that I can insert the data, but now that I have inserted them, I can't ENABLE them (parent key not found). I don't think this has something to do with "INVALID NUMBER" error. But I'm still confused. What should I do?

Comment: 01722 is not the number to be converted but the error number. Otherwise you're right.

Comment: Do **not** store numbers in `varchar` columns. Use a proper `number` data type instead.

Comment: The values in the columns are     `1,020, 0,340....` and so on. I've tried switching to type `number` but i get the same error now, when I try to import the data.

Comment: Have a look at the globalisation guide and your NLS settings, particularly `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARCTERS`. You can specify that explicitly when converting between text and numbers.

Comment: I've solved the problem! the query outputs the SUM. thank you all for the brief answers and solutions.

Comment: Please don't give us your thanks, give us your answer.  SO is a Q&A site, it lives on answers.  It is quite legitimate for you to provide an answer to your own question.  So post your solution, as it may be a benefit to some other seeker.

Comment: I converted the data-import file in Excel from .xls to .csv format, then imported the data in the columns type VARCHAR and the query worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try count() instead of sum(), sum is add number value for each of the input_quant values.  count() is return number count of returned records.

Sum()  works when the datatype is numeric